# Appium inspector can't start session

Tags: python, android, selenium, appium, appium-android

I can't start session in Appium inspector, I have spent all my time but still haven't found a working solution. starting the session is only greeted with:

> Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while
> processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of
> 'C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Programs\Appium Server
> GUI\resources\app\node_modules\appium\node_modules\appium-uiautomator2-server\apks\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.27.0.apk'.
> Original error: The 'java.exe' binary could not be found neither in
> PATH nor under JAVA_HOME (C:\Program Files\Java\bin)

[Error Message in image form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5dnn.png)

"%JAVA_HOME%\bin" is the first thing in my User PATH variable, and JAVA_HOME is set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341"

I'm stuck and don't know what else to do to get the session to start

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just forgot to [set the JAVA_HOME Environment Variable](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html) or you set it wrongly.

Comment: is C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_341 not how you set the JAVA_HOME variable? I don't understand what I did wrong